# reemplazar NA y negativos en un raster-stack

Tags: r, funciones

como ya he mencionado necesito reemplazar los valores negativos y NA´s de un raster-stack por el mínimo ya que me impiden realizar algunos análisis, esto lo he intentado de dos formas:

```
stack <- readRDS('RDS')
stack <- stack(stack)

replaceNA <- function(x, na.rm, ...){ 
  if(is.na(x[1]))
    return(0)
  else
    return(x)
}
stack$capa1 <-  calc(stack$capa1, fun = replaceNA)
```

en este caso únicamente he reemplazado los NAs por cero para una capa especifica

y

```
capa1<- raster('raster1de36')
capa1copia <-capa1
capa1copia[capa1copia<= 0 ] <- NA
capa1[capa1<= 0] <- cellStats(capa1copia, min)
rm(capa1copia)
```

y en este caso todos los negativos por el mínimo

sin embargo solo me ha funcionado para capas individuales y en el raster-stack tengo 36 capas, que solución puedo darle ya que planeo agregar mas capas que seguramente requieren de este mismo procedimiento, ademas de ser posible realizar ambas sustituciones con un mismo conjunto de instrucciones

dejo por un enlace con los datos en RDS por si son necesarios para reproducir los errores https://drive.google.com/file/d/10JE6Ht9TblpFEBCxrsTG71WQ5o3eZEv0/view?usp=sharing

quedo atento a sus comentarios, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de nada, te sugeriría emplear el paquete {terra} en lugar de {raster}, es más moderno y bastante más rápido. La conversión entre ambos paquetes es bastante sencilla, son del mismo desarrollador.

En este ejemplo transformo el dataset a formato {terra}, extraigo el valor mínimo de cada capa y reemplazo los `NAs` de cada capa por el valor del mínimo.

En el último paso lo convierto otra vez a RasterStack y produzco plots para comprobar los valores reemplazados.

Para ahorrar tiempo, en el ejemplo sólo seleccion las 4 primeras capas en el dataset `no_na`, te pongo comentado cómo hacerlo para todas las capas:

```r
stack <- readRDS("predictores_1km31.rds")

library(raster)
stack <- stack(stack)

# Alternativa con terra
library(terra)
#> Warning: package 'terra' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> terra 1.5.21
terra_rast <- rast(stack)


# Ejemplo: selecciona solo 4 layers
# En tu caso reemplaza por esta linea:
# no_na <- terra_rast

no_na <- subset(terra_rast, 1:4)

# Esta es solo para contraste
inicial <- no_na

# Extrae minimo
minmax_vals <- minmax(no_na)[1, ]

minmax_vals
#> accessibility        aspect         bi015         bio01 
#>    -185.92888       0.00000      29.00000      53.70958


# Bucle: reemplaza NAs en cada layer con su minimo
for (i in seq_len(nlyr(no_na))) {
  no_na[[i]][is.na(no_na[[i]])] <- minmax_vals[i]
}

# Comprobaciones-------

# Comprueba el número de NAs iniciales en cada capa
sapply(inicial, function(x) {
  sum(is.na(terra::values(x)))
}, simplify = TRUE)
#> [1]  43859 533643 646217 646217

# Ahora en el nuevo raster: no debería haber ninguno
sapply(no_na, function(x) {
  sum(is.na(terra::values(x)))
}, simplify = TRUE)
#> [1] 0 0 0 0


no_na
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1013, 1025, 4  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
#> extent      : -14548.19, 1010452, 1113786, 2126786  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-90.5 +k=0.9998 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#> sources     : memory  
#>               memory  
#>               memory  
#>               ... and 1 more source(s)
#> names       : accessibility,     aspect,      bi015,      bio01 
#> min values  :    -185.92888,    0.00000,   29.00000,   53.70958 
#> max values  :     1537.5137,   359.4484,   114.6180,   283.9173

# Si necesitas en formato raster::stack
newstack <- raster::stack(no_na)
newstack
#> class      : RasterStack 
#> dimensions : 1013, 1025, 1038325, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
#> extent     : -14548.19, 1010452, 1113786, 2126786  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-90.5 +k=0.9998 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#> names      : accessibility,     aspect,      bi015,      bio01 
#> min values :    -185.92888,    0.00000,   29.00000,   53.70958 
#> max values :     1537.5137,   359.4484,   114.6180,   283.9173

# Comprobamos con plots
# Usamos NA en negro para visualizarlo bien
plot(inicial, colNA="black")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```r
# Tras sustituir, no deberiamos ver negros, sino blancos
# que es el color para el valor minimo en esta paleta de colores

plot(no_na, colNA="black")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>